# Changing the position of my tab bar in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I had a tab bar based application ,and all the work which I did is tab based in that application.

Now I need to change the tab bar position to top from bottom. I tried so many custom tab bars.

But my problem is i just wanted to change the UItabbarcontroller to a custom tab bar controller which can change the position so that I can minimise the edit.

Otherwise I will need to entirely restructure my application. Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the proper way but what i did is create a view and add buttons. I can do what I want with it.